# Что такое делегат в языке С#?

Tags: c#, c#-faq, делегаты

Объясните простым, человеческим языком, кто такой и зачем нужен делегат в ООП вообще и в С# в частности?

Comment: Что-то все ответы какие-то длинные. Кратко: делегат - безопасный (управляемый) указатель на функцию (метод). Всё.

Comment: под словом управляемый подразумевается то что его можно добавить, изменить  или удалить когда угодно?

Comment: Это значит, что использовать его напрямую можно только в управляемом (managed) коде - в платформе .NET.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov к вашему определению не хватает завершающего вопроса: "Понятно, а что такое указатель на функцию?" =) Определение верное, но не слишком понятное для непосвященных.

Comment: @rdorn - а это уже нужно задавать отдельным вопросом :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Делегат — это объектно-ориентированный способ работы с методом как с переменной. Его более привычный аналог — указатель на функцию, функтор, или даже просто вектор прерывания (спасибо @rdorn за подсказку).

Делегат представляет собой тип, соответствующий определённой сигнатуре функции. Объявив переменную делегатного типа, вы можете записать в неё статический или нестатический метод, передать его как аргумент куда-либо, и вызвать.

Классический пример использования делегатов — сортировка списка объектов по значению какого-либо поля. Вы передаёте в сортирующий метод *делегат*, который по объекту вычисляет *ключ сортировки*, то есть, вытаскивает значение поля.

Comment: @rdorn: Ну, делегат это как бы объект, то есть мы оборачиваем функцию именно объектом. Вектора прерываний — это, как мне кажется, всего лишь аналог. А есть где-то применение термина «делегат» не в контексте объекта-обёртки?

Comment: @rdorn все-таки делегат - это не функтор и не указатель на функцию. От указателя на функцию делегат отличается тем, что хранит контекст вызова и может комбинироваться. Функтор же - более широкое понятие чем делегат. Любой делегат есть функтор, но обратное неверно.

Comment: Ну, указатели вроде бы есть только в C и C++ из крупных языков? А, и в Паскале.

Comment: @VladD и еще в IL...

Answer (score 13):

Из справки на MSDN [Делегаты (Руководство по программированию на C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173171.aspx)):

> **Делегат** — это тип, представляющий ссылки на методы с конкретным
>   списком параметров и возвращаемым типом. При создании экземпляра
>   делегата этот экземпляр можно связать с любым методом с совместимой
>   сигнатурой и возвращаемым типом. Метод можно вызвать (активировать) с
>   помощью экземпляра делегата.

Добавлю своими словами: *делегаты можно назвать особыми типами с кодом, генерируемым на этапе выполнения. Также можно сказать, что это своего рода указатели на методы. Вызов делегатов выполняется в том же потоке через метод, вызванный с использованием делегата, причем исключения бросаются так же, как будто метод был вызван напрямую. Вызов делегата с одним методом равносилен обычному вызову метода. Один делегат может вызвать много методов (если подписаны на несколько методов). Касаемо ООП - как уже было сказано, это объектно-ориентированный способ работы с методом. Вообще, тема ООП достаточно большая, поэтому тут только вскользь. Делегат - это такой же тип, как к примеру класс или интерфейс, он может определяться либо внутри класса, либо вне, в пределах пространства имен.*

На ruSO C#-делегаты достаточно популярная тема, вопросы и ответы на которую имеются, для изучения приведу пару примеров:

- [Делегаты и их экземпляры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513286/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D1%8B)
- [Как пользоваться делегатами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575026/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)
- [Делегаты C#. Invoke](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610975/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-c-invoke)
- [c# Делегаты - плюсы и минусы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479412/c-%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B)
- [Когда обычно нужно использовать делегаты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B/277236#277236)

Answer (score 5):

Уже 2 ответа даны. Я добавлю третий вариант, более человечный :)

**Делегат** - лучше всего вспомнить о таком слове как **Представитель**. Это слово будет синонимом или, если хотите, переводом на русский яз. Еще можно вспомнить о слове **Депутат**. Короче, представитель, который представляет в качестве себя одного любимого многих. Депутат представляет выборщиков, много выборщиков. Делегат в языке C# - представляет или может представлять много методов. Этакое отношение один-ко-многим.

Делегат похож на переменную, которая может ссылаться на один или больше методов с одинаковой сигнатурой и возвращаемым типом. После создания делегата с нужной сигнатурой, вы можете подписывать (присоединять к списку вызова этого делегата с помощью операции `+=`) методы или отписывать (удалять из списка вызова операцией `-=`) методы. В дальнейшем использовав вызов делегата, вы производите вызов всех методов, которые ранее были в списке вызова. Еще одна аналогия - список e-mail рассылки - отправка одного письма сразу многим адресатам.

Про использование в ООП: на делегатах основаны события, с помощью делегатов можно создавать анонимные методы (методы без имени), ну и см. ответ уважаемого @VladD.

Comment: т.е. делегат это просто ссылка на метод (или методы)? они нужны для того что бы упростить написание кода ?

Comment: @Сергей не упростить, а ввести в язык ряд новых функциональных возможностей. Упрощает так называемый "синтаксический сахар", а делегат это прежде всего тип в языке, который служит выполнению ряда необходимых задач. Почитайте про `events` (события) - это еще один тип основанный на делегатах.

Comment: спасибо, почитаю

Comment: Вот события - это как раз не тип.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы правы, это я сгоряча сказанул...

Answer (score 5):

Я думаю что остальные излишне сложно написали... Если просто и в двух словах:

### Делегат - это просто обьект, который хранит ссылку(и) на метод(ы).

### Когда мы вызываем делегат с какими-то входными параметрами - это то же самое, что вызвать все методы которые на него подписаны.

Как бы и все обьяснение которое необходимо...

И на примере использования:

```
//Обьявляем делегат
delegate int Mydel(int x, int y); 

//Обьявляем метод, который может быть подписан на делегат. Пример кодом:
static int Sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
// Этот метод должен соответствовать:
// * Иметь такую же сигнатуру как сам делегат (входные параметры)
// * Возвращать такой же тип данных как и делегат
//
// Мой код, как видно, соответствует этому.
```

Использование делегата:

```
// обьявил переменную делегата и подписал метод Sum
Mydel sumDelegate = Sum;

//вызвал метод Sum через sumDelegate
int result = sumDelegate(10, 5);
```

---

### Что нужно иметь ввиду:

- Один делегат может вызвать много методов (если подписаны на несколько методов). (подписывать через `+=` и отписывать через `-=` )
- Вызов делегата делается в том же потоке, в котором находится метод, из которого его вызвали. Это значит, что если у вас есть 2 потока в программе, и нужно вызвать метод, который делает что-то из UI потока, нужно вызвать BeginInvoke.

  Как-то так:

  ```
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(sumDelegate(10, 5));
  ```
- Еще есть предопределенные делегаты `Action` и `Func`. Лично я предпочитаю пользоваться именно ими.
- Еще есть довольно родственное понятие `event`. `Event`- ы основаны на делегатах. Про разницу между ними можно почитать вот здесь: [Event и delegate: в чем отличие?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/226505/event-%D0%B8-delegate-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Action, как и Func, это **не замена** делегатов, это просто несколько **предопределенных** делегатов