# Предобъявление функции c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как создать функцию в c# без тела.
То есть указать только название и параметры.
А потом добавить тело.
Искала в интернете не нашла.
И с обработчиками в WPF можно такое провернуть?

Comment: `Action` и `Func` вам в помощь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Это через делегаты?

Comment: Это разновидность делегатов, да, что-то на подобие этого будет `x=>x + 1` или `() => SomeMethod()`, где `x+1` или `SomeMethod` отдельная логика, о которой не знает тот, кого вы вызываете. Если знакомы с LINQ, то уже с ними наверно сталкивались. Тут можете [почитать](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.33.php).

Comment: Уточните, для чего это вам. А то тут и интерфейс может подойти и абстрактный класс. А может и не подойти. Может перегруженные классы нужны.

Comment: @CrazyElf У меня есть обработчик Textchanged он создаётся в функции 1, а в функции 2 мне надо у Textbox его отключить. И вот я хотела создать его в глобальной области видимости. А тело объявить в функции 1.

Comment: Мне кажется вы изначально не так решаете задачу, ибо в WPF все делается привязками, а не подпиской/отпиской события, а чтоб это понять, нужно знать конкретно как и что вы делаете, а это уже за рамками данного вопроса.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У меня есть обработчик который создаётся в функции 1, а в функции 2 происходит изменение текста и после изменения соответственно вызывается обработчик, а мне этого не надо, так вот я и хотела отключить на время обработчик, а потом включить.

Comment: Это не меняет тот факт, что вы разрабатываете WPF проект не так, как это надо. Вы работаете с ним, как с WinForms проектом, где пишете `MyTextBox1.Text = ..`, тогда вопрос, зачем вам WPF, если вы не используете весь его потенциал и самую главную "силу"? WPF ценится своими привязками (binding) и стилями (xaml) и в нормальном проекте вы вообще не должны хотеть обратиться к текстбоксу или чему-либо еще из XAML, ибо все у вас сводится к свойствам, которые привязываются к UI елементам. То есть, не `MyTextBox.Text = ...`, а `SomeProperty = ...`, а с таким подходом вы вообще забываете про события.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

варианты:

1. делегаты. В том числе Action и Func. [Тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924160/186752)
2. интерфейсы и абстрактные классы/функции
3. создать пустую функцию с пустыми скобками. Если тело должно что-то возвращать - `throw new NotRealizedException;` или просто пустой/случайный результат.

```
public void SomeFunc(int someInt) { } // пустые скобки = пустое тело

public string SomeFunc2(int someInt) { 
    throw new NotRealizedException;
} // заменяешь тело когда необходимо на необходимое.
```

Comment: А можете простой пример написать

Comment: А интерфейсы разве нет? )

Comment: ну интрфейс и протокол это формально одно и то же.... как в каком языке называется) сейчас работаю с языком в котором протоколы а не интерфейсы, вот и здесь написал слово "протоколы", но вообще да, относительно шарпа лучше писать интерфейсы

Comment: Так а как потом добавить тело SomeFunc?

Comment: вписываешь код внутрь фигурных скобок