# Применение делегатов в C#

Tags: c#, делегаты

Здравствуйте не могу понять в чем смысл применения делегатов. Пишут что
**Делегаты позволяют делегировать определение действия из класса во внешний код, который будет использовать этот класс**
На примере этого кода все же не пойму почему именно нужно использовать делегат и каким образом он помогает делегировать определение действия во внешнем коде.

```
public delegate void AccountHandler(string message);
public class Account
{
    int sum;
    // Создаем переменную делегата
    AccountHandler? taken;
    public Account(int sum) => this.sum = sum;
    // Регистрируем делегат
    public void RegisterHandler(AccountHandler del)
    {
        taken = del;
    }
    public void Add(int sum) => this.sum += sum;
    public void Take(int sum)
    {
        if (this.sum >= sum)
        {
            this.sum -= sum;
            // вызываем делегат, передавая ему сообщение
            taken?.Invoke($"Со счета списано {sum} у.е.");
        }
        else
        {
            taken?.Invoke($"Недостаточно средств. Баланс: {this.sum} у.е.");
        }
    }
}
```

Почему в месте вызова делегата не использовать просто Console.Writeline("ТЕКСТ");

Comment: Делегаты используются для передачи методов в качестве аргументов к другим методам (например LINQ), создания обработчиков события (например Click у элемента Button)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое делегат в языке С#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648480/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%a1)

Comment: Вот ответ написанный достаточно простым языком https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924160/186752

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делегаты представляют идею, которая активно применяется в программировании уже несколько десятков лет. Чаще всего эту технику можно встретить в функциональном программировании, но и в императивном она тоже регулярно встречается. В терминах языка C она называется *указатель на функцию*. В C# для неё придумали удобный синтаксис и новое название — делегат.

Она нужна для того, чтобы повторно использовать код, особенно, если это сложный код. В C есть функция `qsort` — это реализация алгоритма быстрой сортировки, которая может упорядочивать данные любого типа.

Алгоритм кажется не очень сложным, но на самом деле не так просто написать его хорошую реализацию. Нам бы, конечно, хотелось разработать универсальную функцию сортировки, чтобы сортировать и числа, и строки, и дату/время, но как это сделать, если для сравнения чисел у нас используется одна операция, для сравнения строк — другая, для даты и времени — третья?

Тут на помощь и приходят внешние функции. Основную стратегию сортировки мы пишем в рамках нашего кода. Для его работы нужна функция сравнения, своя для каждого типа. Такую функцию пишет программист, который будет использовать общую сортировку для своего конкретного типа данных.

Затем он вызывает `qsort` и передаёт одним из параметров *указатель на функцию сравнения*, как сказали бы в C. В C# вместо *указателя на функцию* используют термин *делегат*. Программист на C# точно также пишет свою функцию (свой метод) и передаёт его в качестве параметра в общий метод. Делегат — это тип такого параметра.

В классических императивных языках вам приходится писать обе функции полностью. Но в функциональных языках и современных императивных языках часто применяют лямбда-функции. Вам не приходится описывать вызываемую функцию полностью. Есть упрощённый синтаксис, который позволяет написать несложную функцию прямо в месте вызова.

Это та же самая техника, только ещё более простая с точки зрения программиста.

Отвечая на ваш вопрос:

> Почему в месте вызова делегата не использовать просто `Console.Writeline("ТЕКСТ");`

Скажу, что идея как раз в том, чтобы дать программисту самому решать, что делать в данной ситуации. Возможно, у вас оконное приложение, в котором просто нет консоли, куда можно было бы что-то записать. Вам надо создать окно с сообщением, или обновить индикатор прогресса. А если речь идёт про веб-сервер, то там тоже нельзя просто так ничего писать в консоль. Надо сформировать какой-то JSON и отправить его через TCP-соединение.

Так что здесь у нас есть общий код, который сможет работать и в консольном, и в оконном, и в веб-приложении. Программисту, который будет его использовать, нужно будет написать свои функции-обработчики, которые будут делать правильную работу. В консольном они будут выводить текст в консоль, а в оконном — в окно.

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко, то в данном примере, автор не хотел завязывать класс Account на определенном выводе текста, поэтому он это делегировал вам.

Сейчас у вас сейчас есть возможность прикрутить свой любой вывод текста. В файл, в лог, на консоль... А без этого, вывод был бы только тот, который был бы в Account.